# Cucumber + spring: How to trigger SmartLifecycle events through tests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber

I have a spring boot application with cucumber. I would like to perform certain events within the test BEFORE the start-SmartLifecycle event of the beans is called.

```
Given Something that needs to happen before beans are started
And Beans start up now
Then Life is good
```

Is there any way to achieve this?
By default, it looks like Spring initializes and starts all the beans before any Cucumber statements are executed.

**Example:**

```
class Context {
  @Bean
  SomeBean someBean() { return new SomeBean(); }
}

class SomeBean implements SmartLifecycle {
  @Override
  void start() {
    // some meaningful work that depends on setup that needs to be done beforehand
  }
  // rest of interface implementation
}
```

**Cucumber definitions file:**

```
 @ContextConfiguration(classes = Context.class)
 class CucumberFeatures {
   @Autowired
   private SomeBean someBean;

   @Given("Something that needs to happen before beans are started")
   public void something() {
     // ...
   }

   @Given("Beans start up now")
   public void beansStarted() {
     // This should start beans in their defined order now
   }

   @Then("Life is good")
   public void lifeIsGood() { ... }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't test a dependency injection container while using that same container to inject dependencies into your test. Injecting dependencies requires the application context to have been refreshed already.

So you have to create an instance of the `ApplicationContext` manually and manage it's life-cycle yourself.